# Need a help in the proof of an example of Riesz representation theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

The example said:"A functional $f$ on $l_{2}$ is linear and bounded iff there exists a $y =  (\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, .......) \in l_{2}$ such that for all $x =  (a_{1}, a_{2}, .......) \in l_{2}$, $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k} \bar{\beta_{k}}." $$

For the direction **$\Rightarrow$**,  the statement is true by Riesz representation theorem, for the direction **$\Leftarrow$**, $f(x)$ is clearly linear. Now the proof that $f(x)$ is bounded is as follows:

$|f(x)| = |\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{k} \bar{\beta_{k}}| = |<x,y>| \leq ||x||||y||$ (using Cauchy Schwarz inequality) . hence $||f|| \leq ||y||$..... am I right?

But If so, I have a question, why is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is applicable in infinite dimensional spaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: Cauchy-Schwarz is applicable and hence the functional is bounded. The inequality holds because the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz only uses the structure of inner product spaces, i.e. only uses the properties of inner products and vectors. So no reference to basis, hence dimension, is necessary.

Comment: you mean dimension is unnecessary and why this is not the case for Minkovisky inequality (unless I have a misconception )?

Comment: @Idonotknow
Yes, Cauchy-Schwarz holds _for all_ inner product spaces. I am not sure what the comment on the Minkowski inequality means: It holds in the infinite-dimensional case as well, even for $L^p$ spaces which are more general than the $\ell^p$ ones. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Answer (score 0):

1. Schwarz not Schwartz.
2. If $X$ is a inner product space with inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$ then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$|<x,y>| \le ||x|| \cdot||y||$$
holds, where $||x||=<x,x>^{1/2}$

$ \dim X < \infty $ is not needed.

Comment: for 1- I am sorry, I will correct it :)